# jquery slider ie6 & 7 alignment issues

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

New to jquery. Not sure if this is a javascript or css issue. I would guess the latter, but everything I have tried has failed. Site works great it just doesn't align properly in ie6 or 7.

http://sixpencechildphotography.com/

Any suggestions, would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Here you should add left position in #myslide .cover

```
#myslide .cover {
    height: 450px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 6775px;
}
```